# Transform a c# expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expressionvisitor

I am trying to convert a c# expression. Here is an example result I am looking for. Convert:

```
Expression<Func<TestObj, bool>> filter = p => p.LastName == "Smith";
```

to this:

```
Expression<Func<DynamicItem, bool>> converted = p => p.FieldID == 5 && p.FieldValue == "Smith"
```

FieldID is actually taken via reflection of an attribute on the class as you can see in the code below. The error I'm getting right now is the return from Convert where the error is "Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'"

I have hit a wall and thought maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong here. Here is my code:

```
public class MongoReplaceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
}

public class TestObj
{
    [MongoReplaceAttribute(FieldID = 1)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [MongoReplaceAttribute(FieldID = 2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicItem
{
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string v = "Smith";

        Expression<Func<TestObj, bool>> test = p => p.LastName == v;
        var list = MagicFunction(test);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<DynamicItem> MagicFunction(Expression<Func<TestObj, bool>> filter)
    {
        List<DynamicItem> rands = new List<DynamicItem>() 
        { 
            new DynamicItem 
            { 
                FieldID = 1, 
                FieldValue = "Bob" 
            }, 
            new DynamicItem 
            { 
                FieldID = 2, 
                FieldValue = "Smith" 
            },
            new DynamicItem 
            { 
                FieldID = 1, 
                FieldValue = "Alice" 
            }, 
            new DynamicItem 
            { 
                FieldID = 2, 
                FieldValue = "Smith" 
            } 
        };

        var f2 = Converter<DynamicItem>.Convert(filter);

        return rands.AsQueryable<DynamicItem>().Where(f2);
    }
}

class Converter<TTo>
{
    class ConversionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression newParameter;
        private readonly ParameterExpression oldParameter;

        public ConversionVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameter, ParameterExpression oldParameter)
        {
            this.newParameter = newParameter;
            this.oldParameter = oldParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
        {
            return base.VisitLambda<T>(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            Expression left = this.Visit(node.Left);
            Expression right = this.Visit(node.Right);
            Expression conversion = this.Visit(node.Conversion);

            if (left != node.Left)
            {
                return base.Visit(left);
            }
            else if (right != node.Right)
            {
                var r = base.Visit(right);
                return r;
            }
            else
            {
                return node;
            }
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return newParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression != oldParameter)
            {
                return base.VisitMember(node);
            }

            var s = node.Member;
            var attrReader = s.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MongoReplaceAttribute), true).Cast<MongoReplaceAttribute>();

            //If we are a mongo attribute
            if (attrReader != null && attrReader.Count() > 0)
            {
                var id = attrReader.First().FieldID;
                Expression<Func<DynamicItem, bool>> ret = p => p.FieldID == id && p.FieldValue == (string)GetValue(node);
                ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DynamicItem), "p");
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DynamicItem, bool>>(ret.Body, param);
                return base.Visit(lambda.Body);
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        private object GetValue(MemberExpression member)
        {
            var objectMember = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
            var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
            var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
            return getter();
        }
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TTo, TR>> Convert<TFrom, TR>(
        Expression<Func<TFrom, TR>> e)
    {
        var oldParameter = e.Parameters[0];
        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo), oldParameter.Name);
        var converter = new ConversionVisitor(newParameter, oldParameter);
        var newBody = converter.Visit(e.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTo, TR>>(newBody, newParameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `newBody` in the code below, doesn't seem to be correctly created. `e.Body` is `p.LastName == "Smith"`
but `newBody` is `p.FieldID` instead of expected `p.FieldId==5`. Notice the missing equality comparison.

Hence, in the last line, when you try to create a Lambda of `Func<DynamicItem, bool>`, from a body that returns int (p.FieldId), it throws an error.

This is most probably due to some bug in ConversionVisitor. Debug your ConversionVisitor to see why it creates incorrect body.

```
public static Expression<Func<TTo, TR>> Convert<TFrom, TR>(
    Expression<Func<TFrom, TR>> e)
{
    var oldParameter = e.Parameters[0];
    var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo), oldParameter.Name);
    var converter = new ConversionVisitor(newParameter, oldParameter);
    var newBody = converter.Visit(e.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTo, TR>>(newBody, newParameter);
}
```